# Add a progress bar

Tags: monitoring

Consider a table

```
N=1000000;
table=Table[{i,f[i]},{i,1,N,1}]
```

Is it possible to create a progress bar for being able to see how many rows of table are already evaluated?

Comment: Don't use `N` as a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n = 1000000;
Monitor[table = Table[{i, f[i]}, {i, 1, n, 1}];, i]
```

or, more fancy:

```
Monitor[table = Table[{i, f[i]}, {i, 1, n, 1}];, 
  ProgressIndicator[i, {0, n}]]
```